# how to document.getElementById('id') return be passed to expression function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, expression, selector

I want create a function be used with dom selector ...

looklike : document.getElementById('id').myfunction(arg);

watch:

```
 <div id="test"></div>

    <script>
    var myfunction = function(arg1){

    alert(element_id +' need '+arg1);

    }

    document.getElementById('test').myfunction('help');

    </script>
```

I want get on my alert "test need help" ...

please how can I get the id of  " calling " same as Jquery use $('#test').css(...) for edit css of test element ?

Thanks

Comment: You could extend the HTMLElement prototype, but it's not recommended. Instead, pass the id as the second argument to your function.

Comment: ok thanks, at this time my function use the id on argument . I go to search how to extend the HTMLElement prototype,

Comment: There's a danger your custom extension would contradict a future native property, that's why it is not recommended to extend native prototypes. In jQuery, `$(..)` returns a jQuery object, which contains the selected elements and other properties, it's totally different from monkeypatching native prototypes.

Comment: ok , so I want use it , I need to create a custom object type .... I think the best way for my little function is the id on arg. Thank you